# making dedicated outlet by removing shared connections

Tags: electrical

I have two outlets that are on the same circuit. Is it possible to have one of the unwanted outlets removed / detached so that the other outlet essentially becomes dedicated on that circuit? I need a dedicated outlet for a refrigerator, and at the designated area there is a shared outlet which must be on a dedicated circuit. For practical reasons, I cannot run a new wire from that outlet to the circuit breaker, so I am looking for an "easier" option. Detaching the unwanted outlet seems to be the only easy path.

Comment: Do you know how big  an amp load is this fridge?  Or are you making assumptions "surely it must be..." ?

Comment: Manufacturer is recommending 15 amp dedicated circuit in their specifications.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it's generally fine to remove an outlet, as long as you have enough outlets left to satisfy the requirements in 210.52 (generally an outlet within 6 ft of any point along a wall and within 2 ft of any point along a counter, but read the whole thing).

Splice the wire in the box and replace the outlet cover with a blank cover. The junction box needs to remain accessible, so you can't drywall over it or anything like that.

Note that the refrigerator doesn't always need its own circuit, it can be on one of the 20 A small-appliance circuits that supplies receptacles in your kitchen and dining room. Here is the text of 210.52(B) in the 2020 edition:

[image: NEC 2020 210.52(B)]

Answer (score 2):

### Just don't use the recep

There is no requirement anywhere in Code for a dedicated circuit for a fridge.  It's a luxury, and the main value in it is excluding AFCI and GFCI from it, so you don't get food-spoiling  nuisance trips. In modern wiring fridges don’t really benefit from either.

Whereas, *removing* a receptacle just opens several cans of worms electrically and in the building codes.

### Fridges are a trivial load anyway

They only pull about 100W when they are running.  There's a motor startup surge, but it's quite short, and any competent thermal breaker will tolerate that even with 19A of other loads.

If you are tripping breakers it's time to talk about your other loads, and whether  your breaker has a TEST button.

Comment: The fridge manufacturer is requesting a dedicated circuit. Directly behind the target wall is the kitchen fridge that is on its own dedicated line. So a suggestion put forward by someone else was that we could tap into that line, in which case we would have two refrigerators on the same circuit. This again violates the manufacturers specifications. I thought the easiest path forward would be to remove the other shared outlet from the line that we intend to use for the wine fridge so that it essentially becomes dedicated without having to run a new wire to the circuit breaker.

Comment: @Andrew read carefully.  Is it a *requirement* or a *recommendation*?  There's a big difference. Instructions are UL approved, and I do not see  UL approving instructions which *mandate* a dedicated circuit. For a wine fridge.

Comment: Manufacturer will not install the unit unless there is a dedicated circuit. If you do happen to get it installed somehow, your warranty is void, if something were to happen.

Comment: @Andrew -- what make and model is this insane fridge that somehow *requires* a dedicated circuit?!

Comment: Well, the fact that the *factory* comes out and installs it, suggests it’s *rather* high end/bespoke. The vendor expects their customers will see “running a new dedicated circuit” as trivial.

Comment: @Andrew Since the manufacturer is the one with these _hard_ requirements, you probably better ask them if removing the outlet is an acceptable compromise.

Comment: It is a sub-zero fridge and they insist that the unit must be on a dedicated circuit. Unfortunately, getting a dedicated line put in our home is not a trivial task, it would require a lot of drywall damage. Perhaps removing the other unwanted outlet from that line is the only viable solution. I will reach out to sub-zero to ensure this is OK.